# Стоит ли использовать автоматическую сериализацию в GSON?

Tags: java, json, сериализация, gson

Собственно, вопрос в том, эффективнее ли использовать кастомные Gson сериализаторы/десериализаторы для каждого POJO или проще использовать автоматическую сериализацию доступные в Gson (конечно же, в тех случаях, когда специальная сериализация не требуется)?

Тот же вопрос касается и Jackson (с ним не работал, но насколько я понял, там тоже встаёт аналогичный вопрос).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут решать вам. Но, используя готовые решения(`gson`, `jackson` и пр.) вы получаете:

1. Готовое решение "из коробки". Экономит время разработки
2. Продуманные интерфейсы, позволяющие использование как существующих, так и самописных вариантов решения сериализации/десериализации для "не обычных" случаев
3. Множество литературы и форумов, где в случае чего вы можете найти решение задачи

Использование своих, "кастомных", классов уже будет зависить от того, как вы их реализуете. 
Скорее всего, конечно, они будут чуть менее эффективны(потому как если бы не надо было делать прыжки с реализацией - вы бы не заморачивались).
 Но на деле, если грамотно все сделаете - то разницы не почувствуете

**P.S.:** мы часто в ходе работы используем для преобразования, к примеру, форматов дат, транслитерации данных для конечного пользователя. Проблем не было. Замеры производительности если и отличались, то на миллисекунды а то и то меньше

Comment: Вы не совсем правильно меня поняли (а я не совсем правильно выразился, сейчас отредактирую). Я имею в виду, сравнение использования кастомных GSON - сериализаторов и автоматических GSON - сериализаторов.

Comment: Тут уже зависит КАК вы сами напишете код) Вы же сами понимаете, добавите в свою реализацию бесконечный цикл - и все) А если без шуток - то мы часто используем для передачи, к примеру, пользователям поля с определенным форматом дат. Разницы не заметили. Разве что размер класса стал больше

Comment: @ЯниславКорнев дополнил ответ